# Mining is taking too much cpu memory( i.e more than 100% of one core), how to reduce it?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

**What I have**
 1. I have step up four private blockchain of ethereum.
 2. when i start mining on one core( miner.start(1) ) , it is taking too much cpu memory( i.e 100% or more)

**What I Want**
 1. Mining should take less memory
 2. I have to run four instance of geth on a system, connected to each other( in a peer)

Comment: Take a look at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/minimize-mining-times-for-private-blockchain/12014#12014